# Не отображаеться часть скругленных границ элемента в ie8 при использовании PIE CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Всем доброго дня.При задании border-radius для div для корректного отображения в ie8 подключил CSS3 PIE, скругленные углы появились, но часть границы (правая и нижняя) перестали отображаться.Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой или просто знает ответ, подскажите пожалуйста. Вот ссылка https://www.dropbox.com/s/fpgxgeg2wikv63o/img.jpg

Comment: http://border-radius.com/

Comment: благодарю за ответы, но position: relative or position:absolute + zoom:1 уже пробовал не помогает

Comment: код чего, стилей, разметки или того и того?

Comment: .review{ margin-bottom:20px;-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px; border:1px solid #ededed; padding-bottom:18px;
border-bottom-color:#afdfec;}-вот общая стилизация,
.review{zoom:1; position:relative;behavior: url('/pie/PIE.htc');}-это для ие

Comment: 1)AddType text/x-component .htc - попробуйте это в htaccess добавить 2)попробуйте объекту добавить background: #ccc (цвет или градиент тот который вам нужен)

Comment: AddType text/x-component .htc было прописано, а добавление фона  ничего не меняет